# How to define hibernate mapping for a map of maps

Tags: hibernate

Without worrying about persistence, I had designed a class to hold the quantities of different products mapped by (different sized) containers that the product can be kept in

```
class Inventory {
  Long                             id;
  Map <Long, Map<Long,Integer>>    productQuantityByContainer; // ProductId->(ContainerId -> quantity)
}
```

with the Product and Container classes as

```
class Product {
  Long  id;
  String name;
}

class Container {
  Long     id;
  Double   size;
}
```

The latter two have straight-forward Hibernate mappings to their corresponding database tables. I need to use Hibernate mapping files (hbm.xml) and my database has the following information (without consideration to Hibernate's constraints):

```
Product table
--------------
ID|Name
1  Milk
2  Orange Juice

Container table
---------------
ID |Size(oz)
10  32  
11  64

Inventory table (first 2 columns form the PK)
---------------
Product-ID(FK) | Container-ID(FK) | Quantity
  1              10                   25
  1              11                   15
  2              10                   33
```

My question is: I understand Hibernate does not allow persistence of map of collections. So to make Hibernate persist information from my Inventory class, would it suffice to have my design and mappings as follows? (I create two classes ContainerQuantity and Quantity with two mapping tables of the same name as shown below) Please critique/check my hbm mappings below.

```
class Inventory {   // <--- Redesigned --->
  Long       id;
  Map <Long, ContainerQuantity>    cqsByProduct; // ProductId->ContainerQty
}

<class name="Inventory"> <!-- hbm mapping -->
   <id name="id"/>
   <map name="cqsByProduct">
      <key column="Inventory_ID" not-null="true"/>
      <map-key column="Product_ID"
      <one-to-many class="ContainerQuantity"/>
   </map>
</class>

Inventory table (in Database)
---------------
  id
 90210
 90211

class ContainerQuantity {
  Long                  id;
  Map<Long,Integer>     quantitiesByContainer;
}

<class name="ContainerQuantity"> <!-- hbm mapping -->
   <id name="id"/>
   <map name="quantitiesByContainer">
      <key column="CQ_ID" not-null="true"/>
      <map-key column="Container_ID"
      <one-to-many class="Quantity"/>
   </map>
</class>

ContainerQuantity table (for holding the cqsByProduct collection)
------------------------
   id     | Product_ID  | Inventory_ID (FK to collection owner)  
  101          1            90210
  102          1            90210
  103          2            90210

class Quantity {
  Integer               quantity;
  Container             container; 
  ContainerQuantity     cq;        
}

<class name="Quantity"> <!-- hbm mapping -->
    <composite-id>
       <key-many-to-one name="container" class="Container" column="Container_ID" />
       <key-many-to-one name="cq" class="ContainerQuantity" column="CQ_ID" />
    </composite-id>     
</class>

Quantity table  (for holding quantitiesByContainer collection)
--------------------
 Container_ID(FK) | Quantity | CQ_ID (FK to collection owner)
    10               25         101
    11               15         102
    10               33         103
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tribulation (and with no answers forthcoming on SO), I found the solution to my own question.  Hope this will help someone else in future. I did simplify my design to get rid of the Quantity class because the map in ContainerQuantity can be just a value collection. However, it is noteworthy that not having the Quantity class doesn't stop us from having a "Quantity" table in the database.

```
// classes defined in package hibtest
public class Inventory {
  Long            id;
  String          name;
  Map <Product, ContainerQuantity>    cqsByProduct;

  public Inventory()
  //..getters and setters for each of above
}

public class ContainerQuantity {
   Long                  id;
   Inventory             inventory;
   Map<Container,Integer>     quantitiesByContainer;

   public ContainerQuantity()
  //..getters and setters for each of above
}
```

The hardest part was getting the Hibernate mapping right which turned out to be:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="hibtest.Inventory" table="INVENTORY">
     <id name="id" column="INVENTORY_ID">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">DON.NEXT_INVENTORY_ID</param>
        </generator>
     </id>
     <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
     <map name="cqsByProduct" inverse="true" cascade="all"> <!-- inverse=true ensures INVENTORY_ID in CONTAINERQUANTITY table is set by hibtest.ContainerQuantity -->
        <key column="INVENTORY_ID" not-null="true"/>
        <map-key-many-to-many column="PRODUCT_ID" class="hibtest.Product"/>
        <one-to-many class="hibtest.ContainerQuantity"/>
     </map>
  </class>

  <class name="hibtest.ContainerQuantity" table="CONTAINERQUANTITY">
     <id name="id" column="CQ_ID">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">DON.NEXT_CONTAINERQUANTITY_ID</param>
        </generator>
     </id>

     <many-to-one name="inventory" class="hibtest.Inventory" column="INVENTORY_ID" not-null="true" /> <!-- column will be set when row inserted into CONTAINERQUANTITY table -->

     <map name="quantitiesByContainer" table="QUANTITY" cascade="all" > <!--  inverse is false so CQ_ID in QUANTITY will be set by ContainerQuantity -->
       <key column="CQ_ID" not-null="true"/>
       <map-key-many-to-many column="CONTAINER_ID" class="hibtest.Container"/>       
       <element column="quantity" type="int"/>
     </map>
  </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

My tables look so (Oracle sql):

```
create table product
(
  id               NUMBER(22) not null,
  name             VARCHAR2(32) not null);

create table container
(
  id             NUMBER(22) not null,
  name           VARCHAR2(32) not null);

create table inventory
(
 INVENTORY_ID             NUMBER(22) not null,
 name                     VARCHAR2(32) not null);

create table containerquantity
(
 cq_id                    NUMBER(22) not null,
 product_id               NUMBER(22),
 inventory_id             NUMBER(22));

create table quantity
(
 quantity                 NUMBER(10) not null,
 container_id             NUMBER(22) not null,
 cq_id                    NUMBER(22) not null);
```

Here is the driver code:

```
private static void persist(Session session){
    Product product1 = new Product();
    Product product2 = new Product();       
    product1.setName("Apple");
    product2.setName("Milk");

    Container c1 = new Container();
    Container c2 = new Container();
    c1.setName("32 oz");
    c2.setName("64 oz");

    //-- Make container-qty1 and add 2 quantity entries into it
    ContainerQuantity cq1 = new ContainerQuantity();

    Map<Container,Integer>     quantitiesByContainer1 = new HashMap<Container,Integer>();

    quantitiesByContainer1.put(c1, Integer.valueOf(25));
    quantitiesByContainer1.put(c2, Integer.valueOf(15));
    cq1.setQuantitiesByContainer(quantitiesByContainer1);

    //-- Make container-qty2 and add 1 quantity entry into it
    ContainerQuantity cq2 = new ContainerQuantity();

    Map<Container,Integer>     quantitiesByContainer2 = new HashMap<Container,Integer>();

    quantitiesByContainer2.put(c1, Integer.valueOf(33));
    cq2.setQuantitiesByContainer(quantitiesByContainer2);

    //-- Make Inventory object 
    Inventory inv = new Inventory(); inv.setName("foods");
    Map <Product, ContainerQuantity>    cqsByProduct = new HashMap<Product, ContainerQuantity>();
    cqsByProduct.put(product1, cq1);
    cqsByProduct.put(product2, cq2);

    //-- Set back-reference to inventory on ContainerQuantity objects 
    cq1.setInventory(inv);
    cq2.setInventory(inv);

    inv.setCqsByProduct(cqsByProduct);      

    session.save(product1);
    session.save(product2);
    session.save(c1);
    session.save(c2);

    session.save(inv);      
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with annotations?